# Profile options are redirecting to account settings and not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails. I'm setting up the user profile and adding fields to it for users to of course modify their profile information such as career, about me, height, religion, etc. This information is completely different from the registration options (account settings).

The issue I'm having is that the profile page will forward back to the account settings and say you have to enter your password and it shows all the account settings fields and not the profile fields. So what I need is for the profile page to remain on that page after user submits information, and I need for that information to save to their account so they can modify it later.

Here's the show.html file which is for the user profile:

```
<h1><%= @user.username %></h1>

<h2>Basics</h2>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :height %><br/>
        <%= f.select :about_me, [['Feet', nil], '4', '5', '6'] %>
        <%= f.select :about_me, [['Inches', nil], '0', '1', '2', '3', '4',                  
                                '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11'] %>
        </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :career %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :career %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions"><%= f.submit %></div>
<% end %>
```

Here's the users controller and I know I have it redirecting to @user which sends it back to the account settings page but I don't know what value to set it to so it doesn't:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.show_profile(params[:user])
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

    def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def destroy
     User.find(params[:id]).destroy
     flash[:success] = "User deleted."
     redirect_to users_url
   end

def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Account updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Show method is doing what it is meant for. It is showing the view for you. As you defined it, it should be redirected to the user for which the profile is to be shown and so is doing here.

Your task is to call the create method whatever the case is:

So what you need to do is:

**Method one** is to define your code in `new.html.erb` for what you defined in `show.html.erb`.

Doing so, will not need to explicitly define your path in `form_for` as form will call create method internally.

**Method two** is to explicitly define your path in the form_for as:

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => {:action => :create}) do |f| %>
```

Please note that the method one is the recommended way of doing what you need because it is the work of create action to do the post method work and then do database related task.

Comment: I have new.html.erb set for when a person registers with the website. What I am trying to do is for the register user to enter their profile information. When the user register they only entered in the account settings. Now when they login they can fill out their profiles. It doesn't sound like your solution  address that, but please correct me if I'm wrong. Also I'm thinking the action should be update since I am not creating a new user. Or is it create since it's essentially creating a new profile?

Comment: update action works for user edit just like create action works for user new. Since you are not editing the user details, it's not update that you should call. So you can create custom action and provide functionality there.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. I have tried a few variations but nothing has work as far as your Method one is concern. Can you provide me an example? I would still like to come up with it on my own but some sort of example would help me out a little more as I'm new to programming. I'm trying to figure it out though still in the meantime

Comment: As your first comment says that you have already used new action for registration so my method one is of no use for you. Try method 2 but for that just rename your `show.html.erb` with `profile.html.erb`. Then create action `def profile` that contains the create action code. Define your custom action in your `routes.rb`.

Comment: I think that you resolved your this question's problem and kept the new question. If you found my answer usefull than you can upvote or accept as you want.

Comment: I am still working this question. Then new question was made because I could not get the route to work for displaying the /profile page.  I am still trying to have the /profile page (or even /show) update those profile fields. As of now the profile fields are being recognized as the registration fields, which is incorrect. When I click "Update" on profile page, it redirects to registration page. So the profile page with all those fields have no value atm. The system is not recogonizing that those values should be saved to the user profile.

Comment: this is because you used 'match profile#id => show'  which is wrong. the show action is for registeration. that was the answer you accepted as correct.

Comment: The question I asked on the other post has nothing to do with this question. That question was for getting the route of profile page to work, which it did. I can now go to /profile and it shows. The only problem I have not are the profile field options are not set. I have all the forms on it, but I need for my  application to recognize that these profile options are not part of the user registration and for all the information the user fills out on the profile page (/profile/id-here or /users/id-here) that it saves that information to their account. My github https://github.com/pwz2k/date